# Localtunnel is not working for node and react

Tags: node.js, web, backend, localtunnel

```
lt --port 3000 --subdomain 8934ryu983ygf9834h589ty34hi
```

This command usually return a url when successful. It is returning nothing for 2 days.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Apparently the localtunnel services are down (see : [enter link description here](https://github.com/localtunnel/localtunnel/issues/503))